# super() in inherited class that will be inherited with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

If one has a class that inherits, and uses `super()` to refer to the parent class, and then inherits from that class using multiple inheritance, `super()` gets confused and no longer looks at the current class's parent. For example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A class')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('B class')
        super().__init__()

class C(A):
   def __init__(self):
        print('C class')
        super().__init__()

class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
print(D.__mro__)
print(C.__mro__)
D()
```

This produces the output:

```
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
C class
B class
A class
```

The problem is that `super()` in `class C` looks at the `__mro__` (method resolution order) from `D` and sees that `C` is followed by `B`, ignoring that fact that the `__mro__` for `C` doesn't contain `B`.

Edit:

In that case there are no errors caused by this behavior, and functionality is gained by assuring that `B.__init__` gets called. But in a slightly more complicated example the inheritance in the final class causes the mid-level class to crash, even though it works on its own:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A class')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x):
        print('B class')
        super().__init__()

class C(A):
   def __init__(self):
        print('C class')
        super().__init__()

class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self, x):
        C.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self, x)

C()    
D(1)
```

Output:

```
C class
A class
C class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inherit.py", line 21, in <module>
    D(1)
  File "inherit.py", line 17, in __init__
    C.__init__(self)
  File "inherit.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: B.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

So, is this just not a good case for `super()`? One could obviously just call `A.__init__()` directly. But before the multiple inheritance `super()` was the 'obvious way to do it'. And if this is not when `super()` is supposed to be used, when is it useful?

Comment: this is how *super is supposed to work*. This is kind of the whole point: to support cooperative multiple inheritance

Comment: There are many good websites out there that explain how multiple inheritance works in Python.  super() is specifically *not* the superclass in this situation.

Comment: `super` is analogous to the more appropriately named `next-method` function in Dylan. It's not an alias for the (or any) superclass of the class under construction; it's a type whose instances act as a proxy for the next appropriate class in the MRO of the *object* that delegated its attribute lookup to the `super` instance. I.e, `super().__init__()`, or more explicitly `super(self, C).__init__()`, looks for the `__init__` attribute provided by a class in `type(self).__mro__` that comes after `C`.

Answer (score 1):

> ... , ignoring that fact that the `__mro__` for C doesn't contain B.

The `__mro__` for D contains B.

`class D` is at the bottom of diamond inheritance.
Everything is
[working](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#resolving-mro-entries)
[correctly](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance).

In a more complex example,
we likely would find that classes `B` and `C` each maintain separate
[class invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant),
which shall hold once the object constructor has finished.
And that's above and beyond invariants which `A` maintains.
So `D`, which cooperates with them via `super()`,
must call those constructors before running its own logic.
In this way the code can comply with the
[LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).
Everyone has promises to keep,
and `super()` helps them accomplish that.

EDIT

(Informally, ctor side effects such as logging is "cheating",
it's outside of what OOP encapsulation is driving at.)

Class A has state and behavior.
It maintains class invariants,
from the moment its ctor returns.
Clients who call into it see contracts honored,
so they shall not see invariants violated.

B, C, and D work similarly.
They rely on promises from above
(ultimately from `A` and `object`)
and they make good on promises to clients below.
That includes classes further down the diamond
plus app-level callers.

Consider this example:

- A: models experimental observations such as [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) electric charge, with text label and some numeric attributes, where client may possibly set the charge to "unobserved" `NaN`
- B: records charge measurements using Vendor B's lab equipment
- C: records charge measurements using Vendor C's product, which produces somewhat different metadata attributes from B's product
- D: imposes a [total order](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) on those charges, implying that clients may not specify `NaN`

When we're at the middle level of the diamond,
we're picking an equipment vendor.
If we choose to go to its bottom level,
we're making a decision about data cleanliness
and enabling new sorting-based analysis functions such as
[iqr()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range).
Let's suppose the B & C ctors make a note of the
serial number of the attached lab measurement instrument,
or promise to throw fatal error if it's offline.
Time to exercise those classes.

(1.) App reads a spreadsheet and uses A as a
[DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)
to represent historic observations,
perhaps relying on simple methods that
format timestamp of observation one way or another.

(2.) Now we power on a piece of lab equipment
and make some new measurements.
The app used either B or C to do this.

(3.) Finally we do the same and ask for an IQR analysis via D.

In each case we could take advantage of
[subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_subtyping)
to still accomplish the same goals.
The spreadsheet analysis of (1) could have used C or D
since they are subtypes, they do not mess up A's promises.
The measurement activity of (2) could use D, similarly.

Now, if the middle layer of the diamond regrettably
added a `.measure()` method, (2) would be constrained
by D's `__mro__` and whichever vendor's gear happened
to be available for use.
But there's no requirement for such a name.
B might choose to implement `.measure_b()` and
C similarly `.measure_c()`,
so the app enjoys the best of both worlds.

There are good reasons for `super()`
to offer the behavior that it does.
It helps cooperating classes construct large useful applications.

Comment: The problem here is that this *breaks* LSP as I understand it. When C() is created directly, super() goes to A, but when C's initiator is called from D, its behavior changes. In the original example the problem is not manifest, but I'll put up an example that brings it to light.

Comment: Linearization of base classes transcends the LSP; it's the linearization that *determines* how LSP should be applied. (That is, according to the linearization, an instance of `D` is "more like" an `A` than it is a `B`, because it is more like a `C` than it is a `B` and a `C` is clearly more like an `A` than it is an unrelated `B`.)

Answer (score 0):

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), in their terse way, point out that even though this is a proper use of `super()` in single inheritance, it is not a good use for cooperative multiple inheritance, that is, class structures that have sibling classes "where multiple base classes implement the same method. Good design dictates that such implementations have the same calling signature in every case." If one class implements a method with different attributes than another, we would have to know which version of the method we are calling; and we can't know that when writing the base class, as the inheriting class can change the order on us, like in the current example.

Single inheritance (through the instance creation, as proven by the example here) doesn't have this issue -- we know what the `super` function (O.K., proxy object) refers to. So in that case it makes sense to use `super` on the `__init__` method, even though other classes use the same method with different signatures.

In multiple inheritance, however, this will not work. It is often not feasible for `__init__` to always have the same signature, as each component class has its own needs for its unique role. We can't give `__init__` a unique name either. So just using `super()` will not work.

One workaround for this issue is suggested in a [Real Python tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-super/#method-resolution-order), to put `**kwargs` at the end of each call to `__init__`, so that each initializer can give all the proper attributes to every other one.

I prefer the explicit calling of the parent class by name, when we can know that the only other class we need to worry about at the moment is the parent class or another know class. 'Explicit is better than implicit.'